# How do I pass mouse events from a Popup to another control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, popup

I have a DataTemplate that is used by a ListBox to provide the 'look' for each ListBoxItem. In addition and because these ListBoxItems can be wider than the column in which they're held, I also have a Popup that is drawn over the top of the ListBoxItem if the mouse is over this item.
The Popup uses the same ContentTemplate as the item it covers and therefore the appearance is that the item under the mouse simply stops clipping to the bounds of the ListBox it resides in. It works well except I cannot successfully pass mouse events back to the control it is obscuring, so that the underlying control can detect a drag operation starting.

```
<!--This datatemplate is used to create a popup over the listboxitem in ItemsView.xaml-->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PopupDaybookItemDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel x:Name="pdidt">
                <Popup x:Name="myPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Placement="Relative"  StaysOpen="True">
                    <Popup.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=myPopup, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay, ElementName=pdidt, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Popup.Style>
                    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource DayBookItemStyle}"
                            PreviewMouseDown="ItemListPopup_OnMouseButtonEvent"                              
                            MouseDown="ItemListPopup_OnMouseButtonEvent" 
                            PreviewMouseMove="ItemListPopup_OnMouseEvent"
                            MouseMove="ItemListPopup_OnMouseEvent"
                                 >
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DaybookItemDataTemplate}"
                            PreviewMouseDown="ItemListPopup_OnMouseButtonEvent"                              
                            MouseDown="ItemListPopup_OnMouseButtonEvent" 
                            PreviewMouseMove="ItemListPopup_OnMouseEvent"
                            MouseMove="ItemListPopup_OnMouseEvent"
                         /> 
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </Popup>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyItemPresenter" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DaybookItemDataTemplate}" ></ContentPresenter>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Notice the events tied to both the ListBoxItem and the ContentPresenter within the Popup. They are tied to the following code-behind:

```
private void ItemListPopup_OnMouseButtonEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup popup = (((DependencyObject)sender).GetVisualParent<Popup>());
        popup.PlacementTarget.RaiseEvent(e);
    }

    private void ItemListPopup_OnMouseEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup popup = (((DependencyObject)sender).GetVisualParent<Popup>());
        popup.PlacementTarget.RaiseEvent(e);
    }
```

The PlacementTarget is the ListBoxItem that is being drawn over.
The MouseDown on the ContentPresenter is what allows the underlying ListViewItem to know it has been clicked and therefore selected, and that is working fine. The MouseDown on the ListBoxItem does not, against my expectations. (whether or not the ContentPresenter MouseDown event is hooked).
The other events seem to perform no useful task but I include them because I think they're an obvious thing to try.

I expected that relaying the MouseDown and MouseMove events to the underlying ListBox would allow it to detect a drag operation but it does not. I have also tried passing ALL mouse events in this way (tunnelling and bubbling) but drag operations still do not start.
The underlying control detects drag operations perfectly if the Popup is (permanently) disabled, however disabling the Popup within the mouse event does not help.

I have tried setting the Popup IsHitTestVisible to false but that doesn't help - I guess because the Popup is a separate Window and not part of the Visual Tree therefore there isn't anywhere for the events to bubble up to?

I have also tried changing the mouseEvent.Source but I get a runtime error "Cannot change the RoutedEvent property while the event is being routed". I tried to 'fake' a routed event but couldn't work out how to.

Any help appreciated. Oh and I'm new here so if I break etiquette please let me know.

Comment: You might have more luck with just using `Grid` controls with dynamic column widths to 'make the content fit' into whatever space is available in each `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't explain properly. Imagine a narrow ListBox populated with ListBoxItems that have wide text content, so just the start of each bit of text is visible. The ListBox is in a dockable pane so it could be anywhere! When (and only when) the mouse is over a given ListBoxItem, the Popup is used to redraw that item over the one in the ListBox. As the Popup imitates the item but isn't clipped to the bounds of the ListBox, it appears the item draws itself full-width when the mouse is over, even if that means drawing over other UI or escaping the right edge of the Window entirely.

Comment: Can't you just have it passed to some other method from your code behind in an event ?

Comment: Perhaps, but that would mean learning how to initiate a drag in the library I'm using. I'd rather work out how I can make a Popup truly transparent to mouse activity so the controls underneath it can interact with the mouse.